# Save Microsoft Account in Keychain for Windows Server?

Tags: windows, password, keychain, login, server.app

I regularly connect to a Windows file server that uses a Microsoft account login (email address + password). Every time I connect, my MacOS (10.14, but also 10.13 and 10.12 previously) asks me for the login info. It won't save the email and password required. (It saves the first part of the email address, before the @, but not after the @ and not the password).

Is there a way to make my Mac automatically fill in this information when I go to connect?

Comment: What are you connecting via? Unless it's an app the keychain can't 'see' properly, remote server connections can usually be saved the same as any file host.

Comment: In Finder, sometimes through the Server under Locations in the sidebar, but usually via a Favorite alias I have to a particular folder on the server.